# Java filter how to keep null values

Tags: java, filter, return

Code:

```
Stream<DbPacket> dbPackets = getDataContext(false, isTrue).getPackets().values()
                .stream();
dbPackets = dbPackets.filter(
                        dbPacket -> "A".equals(dbPacket.getTariff().getCode()));
```

Not every Packet can have Tariff, for example:

Packet 1 have Tariff, Code A

Packet 2 have Tariff, Code B

Packet 3 don't have Tariff and don't have Code

So in some cases `dbPacket.getTariff().getCode()` can be null. I need to edit my code, that if Packet don't have Tariff, and `dbPacket.getTariff().getCode()` is null, then filter will keep this Packet. In this case system have to return Packet 1 (because Code is A) and Packet 3 (because Packet don't have Tariff and Code). How can I modify my code?

Comment: Does `dbPacket.getTariff() == null || dbPacket.getTariff().getCode() == null || "A".equals(dbPacket.getTariff().getCode())`not work?

Comment: @Reporter Tried. Then getting error, that `dbPacket.getTariff().getCode()` is null

Comment: Are sure? `dbPacket.getTariff().getCode() == null` is a standard check of null and should be true.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from doing this?

```
dbPackets = dbPackets.filter(
                dbPacket -> dbPacket.getTariff() == null || "A".equals(dbPacket.getTariff().getCode() || dbPacket.getTariff().getCode() == null );
```

Comment: A side question: maybe you did mean `== null`, if not what is the meaning of `Null`?

Comment: Tried. Getting error: `The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) String, boolean`

Comment: @TtT You're probably missing `== null` at the end.